# How can I locate a planet with a specific name?

Tags: starbound

Before the world and character reset, I had made my home on a desert planet in the (Beta) Arrakis system. For obvious reasons, I would like to do so again, but I have no idea of how to locate a system named Arrakis, much less one with a desert planet. What format is the universe data in and how can I view it to try to search for one?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know of to find a specific planet is to know its coordinates, and even that isn't guaranteed to work between updates. Seeing as how this is still early beta, I would advise not getting too attached to anything right now.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I want to know how to browse through the save files for one. I did locate another by just scrolling through a couple thousand systems on the map, but that's a major pain.

Comment: I suspect this isn't quite how the universe works. I don't think there's a file somewhere with the entire universe laid out in it. There's an algorithm somewhere which lets the game calculate on the fly what each planet will be, and only once you land on the planet does that planet get its own file. It may be possible to write an outside script that would let you see the entire universe, but I don't believe it can be done by looking at a file. This is all just speculation, but from looking at the "universe" folder, I'm fairly confident.

Comment: I'm assuming there is a saved random seed for the universe that it generates from, and that while planets in the sense of the 2d worlds you walk on may be generated on the fly, star system names, positions, and planet positions and general biomes are predetermined by that seed. I'm basing this off the fact that you can browse star systems through the travel screen without actually flying to them.

Comment: That's partially true. The universe seed is not random; everyone has the same one. Planets use their coordinates as their seed, so, because everyone has the same universe seed, if you tell someone else the coordinates of a planet, they will be able to go there and find the exact same planet!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the planet characteristics are determined by their coordinates.  Each planet will have a file to it in the Universe folder

File name is set as `<quadrant>_<X Coord>_<unknown>_<unknown>_<Unkonwn>`